# Setting img src on dynamically created img element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a thumbnail image element that is created dynamically through an Ajax call.
Ids and urls are dynamic as well.

```
<img class="tn" id="'+id+'" src="'+d.aUrl+'" />
```

All I want to do, is detect the load error and serve a different image.

**Strategy 1**

Detect load error and set source

```
$(document).on('error', '.tn', function(e){
 $(e.currentTarget.id).attr('src', 'alt_pic.jpg');
 });
```

The issue here is that error event is not detected. When I replace 'error' with 'mouseover', I can see that the correct event is detected for the correct id.

**Strategy 2**

Detect error event from within the image tag and then trigger a function to process.

```
<img class="tn" id="'+id+'" src="'+d.aUrl+'" onerror="replace_image(this)" />

function replace_image(t){
 $(t.id).attr("src", "alt_pic.jpg");
});
```

The error registers and the function is called with the id. This does not work because the image tag was dynamically created and not available in the dom.

Any ideas how to target the image tag?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `$(t.id)` evaluates to `$('tn')` where as what you want is `$('#tn')` or `$(obj)`. Modify your code to either of the variations below:

```js
// replace with alt image
function replace_image(t){
    $(t).attr("src", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffjPe.png");
    // $('#' + t.id) will also work
};

// dynamically insert image
$('div').html('<img id="tn" src="test.jpg" onerror="replace_image(this)" />');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Goran. Just using the complete object (t) worked. Fantastic - I really appreciate your help!!